# Should HDL code be modified with delays if post-synthesis simulation is not expected?

Tags: fpga, verilog, simulation, rtl

I'm very interested in but pretty new to hardware development. I have designed a *101 sequence detector* using the *Verilog* language, but I saw a difference in behaviour simulation and post-synthesis functional/timing simulations.

**What should I do next to improve the design? Should I eliminate this difference by doing something?**

Thanks for any guidelines.

Verilog Code

```vhdl
module top(din,dout,reset,clock);
    
    // Module arguments
    input wire  din;
    output reg  dout;
    input wire  reset;
    input wire  clock;
    
    // Enums
    localparam State$S00 = 0;
    localparam State$S01 = 1;
    localparam State$S10 = 2;
    localparam State$S11 = 3;
    
    // Stub signals
    reg  [1:0] state$d;
    wire  [1:0] state$q;
    reg  state$clock;
    
    // Sub module instances
    top$state state(
        .d(state$d),
        .q(state$q),
        .clock(state$clock)
    );
    
    // Update code
    always @(*) begin
        state$clock = clock;
        state$d = state$q;
        if (reset) begin
            state$d = State$S00;
            dout = 1'b0;
        end
        else begin
            case (state$q)
                State$S00:
                    begin
                        if (din) begin
                            state$d = State$S01;
                        end
                        else begin
                            state$d = State$S00;
                        end
                        dout = 1'b0;
                    end
                State$S01:
                    begin
                        if (din) begin
                            state$d = State$S11;
                        end
                        else begin
                            state$d = State$S10;
                        end
                        dout = 1'b0;
                    end
                State$S10:
                    begin
                        if (din) begin
                            state$d = State$S01;
                            dout = 1'b1;
                        end
                        else begin
                            state$d = State$S00;
                            dout = 1'b0;
                        end
                    end
                State$S11:
                    begin
                        if (din) begin
                            state$d = State$S11;
                        end
                        else begin
                            state$d = State$S10;
                        end
                        dout = 1'b0;
                    end
            endcase
        end
    end
    
endmodule // top


module top$state(d,q,clock);
    
    // Module arguments
    input wire  [1:0] d;
    output reg  [1:0] q;
    input wire  clock;
    
    // Enums
    localparam State$S00 = 0;
    localparam State$S01 = 1;
    localparam State$S10 = 2;
    localparam State$S11 = 3;
    
    // Update code (custom)
    initial begin
       q = 64'h0;
    end
    
    always @(posedge clock) begin
       q <= d;
    end
          
endmodule // top$state
```

Behaviour Simulation (all things are as expected)
[image]

Post-synthesis functional Simulation (should this kind of unwanted glitch be eliminated?)
[image]

Post-synthesis timing Simulation (why does glitch disappear? Why the duration of output level is shortened?)
[image]

Comment: Start learning to use NBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are changing the value of `din` at exactly the same time that `clk` rises. That will cause unpredictable behavior in simulation and in real life. Change your testbench.

Comment: yes, that was exactly how I simulated `din` sequence. Thanks Elliot!

Answer (score 1):

Glitches are expected in post-synthesis simulation (with or without timing) on signals such as `dout` which are driven by combinational logic.

If `dout` will be sampled by clocked logic, such as connecting it to the D input of a flip flop, then there is no reason to eliminate the glitches.

If `dout` is used as a clock signal or an asynchronous reset, then you would most likely want to eliminate the glitches.

One simple way to eliminate the glitch is to pass the signal through another flip flop, and use that flop output as the module output:

```
always @(posegde clock) dout_del <= dout;
```

This will add one clock cycle of latency to your output, which might be fine; you must decide if the latency is acceptable or not.

Another way is to redesign your logic to assure `dout` is sequential logic (directly driven inside an `always @(posegde clock)` block).

---

A bigger issue is that your post-synthesis simulations both show functional differences compared to the pre-synth simulation.

`dout` does not go high when i=3 in your 2nd and 3rd waveform images.  This could point to a design bug in your RTL code.

And, as you've noted, the 3rd waveform could point to timing issues as well.

---

Visually inspecting your Verilog code, I see one potential design issue.  You are deriving a clock signal from another clock:

```
always @(*) begin
    state$clock = clock;
```

This could cause problems for both simulation and synthesis.

One improvement is to use the `clock` signal directly for all your logic and eliminating `state$clock`.

---

You could simplify your code by removing the `top$state` module, and just paste the code directly into the `top` module.  This is just a coding style change (not a functional change).

Comment: Thanks for giving me such detailed explanations and suggestions, which indeed make me  better understand the convention in design. I will try :)